# Regex to insert a character at the beginning of each word

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am scraping twitter for trending topics are currently have a list like this

```
            Trending_Topics
             #facebookdown              
             Lena Dunham  
     #SaveThePlanetIn4Words   
     #NationalPunctuationDay     
             Lane Kiffin
```

I want to now insert a '+' sign in front of each word in the string

However, my current code

```
 df3['Keywords'] = df3.Trending_Topics.str.replace(r'(\b\S)', r'+\1')
```

places the '+' behind the # for the hashtag string

```
 Trending_Topics
 #+facebookdown
 #+SavethePlanetIn4Words
 etc...
```

Ideally, my output would look as so

```
                Trending_Topics
             +#facebookdown              
             +Lena +Dunham  
     +#SaveThePlanetIn4Words   
     +#NationalPunctuationDay     
             +Lane +Kiffin
```

Is there a simple regex solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookbehind assertion.

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(\S)', r'+\1', st)
```

`(?<!\S)` asserts that the match won't be preceded by any non-space character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oR6gU7/1)

EXample:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''             #facebookdown              
             Lena Dunham  
     #SaveThePlanetIn4Words   
     #NationalPunctuationDay     
             Lane Kiffin   '''
>>> print(re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(\S)', r'+\1', s))
             +#facebookdown              
             +Lena +Dunham  
     +#SaveThePlanetIn4Words   
     +#NationalPunctuationDay     
             +Lane +Kiffin
```

Comment: used your code to come up with this: df3['Keywords'] = df3.Trending_Topics.str.replace(r'(?<!\S)(\S)', r'+\1')

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<=\s|^)(?=\S)', re.MULTILINE)

result = re.sub(p, u"+", input)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM6cP6/1)

**Regex pattern breakup:**

```
(?<=\s|^)  # assert if previous position is a space or line start
(?=\S)     # assert if next position is a non-space character
```